# Calculate baking time for bread

Tags: baking

I have a standard long-raising bread I use to make and bake in a cassarole. During this holiday I wanted to bake a double-sized bread. However,I ended up only giving it 150% baking time, and not 200%.

Are the sources that can help you calculate how long approximately your bread needs to be baked given size, floor and water composition, etc. ?

Example-recipee:

```
400 g flour
300 ml water
1 small ball of yeast
Raise for 18 hours
Baked for 30 minutes in 250 celcius closed heated cassarole. 
Baked 10 minutes without lid.
```

Double up:

```
800 g flour
600 ml water
2 small balls of yeast
Raise for 18 hours
Baked for **45 minutes** in 250 celcius closed heated cassarole
Baked for 10-15 minutes without lid.
```

Comment: When writing measurements for flour, I'd suggest writing it as 400 grammes flour, rather than 400 grams flour. "Gram Flour" is an ingredient all of its own, and I originally read your first line as 400gms of "Gram Flour".

Comment: Even better, just use the standard abbreviation: 400 g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I cannot guess a time. What works is temperature. Bread is done at an internal temperature of 195F to 205F (90.5-96.1C).

Comment: The temperature for this particular recipie would be in the higher end of that range. I'd aim for 95°C, 205°F.

Comment: If you don't want to poke a hole with a thermometer, there's always the "soundcheck" (english name, anyone?): tap the underside of the bread *directly from the oven*. It should sound "hollow", a bit like a dry clay pot. But note: this only works within the first minute or so after taking it out and only for breads with a nice crust. OP's recipie should qualify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are such sources. The time depends on too many things, such as the shape of the bread loaf, the reflectivity of the bread pan, the ratio of conductive to radiative heat produced by your oven, to name just a few.

As with any other food, you bake it until it's baked, period. Time doesn't matter. If you have to organize a schedule and so need an approximation for your time plan, you need prior experience with how long this exact recipe took in your own kitchen.