# Bread Cooktime Calculator

Tags: bread, cooking-time

A similarly-titled question [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/52073/26238) does not answer mine.

Is there any way to calculate bread cooktimes by taking approximate dimensions, cook time, and perhaps other factors, such as thermal mass of the oven ?

Comment: No. IMO. You could get a good starting time at which to start checking it but there are just too many variables in a home kitchen. The duty cycle of your oven, how humid the day is, hydration of the dough, flour composition, risiness (fluffiness) of the bread, etc. Once you have a result you like it should be reproducible- but coming up with an exact time for a new recipe is impossible. This isn't really an answer- just an opinion. Perhaps someone else knows of an infallible table.

Comment: That would be great, but as @Sobachatina said, sounds either impossible or really expensive.